# How to make instance of SKViaPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

There were no examples in the Demo App and I cannot figure out how to make an instance of SKViaPoint object.

It is only mentioned SKRoutingService.h but even there I couldn't find any more info about it.

Class SKViaPoint.h is not in the project, or I cannot find it via search.

something like:

```
SKViaPoint* viaPoint = [[SKViaPoint alloc] init];
```

doesn't work, so can anybody please help me out with this?

Link to documentation:

[Skobbler Api Documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKViaPoint.html#//api/name/coordinate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples in the demo project, i.e.:

```
SKViaPoint *point = [SKViaPoint viaPoint:1 withCoordinate:coordinate];
```

where the method definition (from SkViaPoint.h) is

```
** A newly initialized SKViaPoint object.
 @param viaPointID The unique identifier of the viapoint.
 @param viaPointCoordinate The location of the viapoint.
 */
+ (instancetype)viaPoint:(int)viaPointID withCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)viaPointCoordinate;
```